# C: Syntax error: identifier 'Block'

Tags: c, syntax

I'm having issue with a struct I have created

```
typedef struct _BLOCK
{
    int size;
    int offset;
    Block *nextBlock;

} Block;
```

the compiler doesn't recognise the identifier for the *nextBlock pointer

also compiler doesn't seem to recognise the "Block" struct at any point in the program, i use it as an argument in a few methods and errors like "syntax error: missing '{' before '*'" occur. any insights would be helpful

Comment: Names starting with `_` plus an uppercase letter or another underscore are reserved for the implementation. **Don't use them**

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon:

```
struct _BLOCK *nextBlock;
```

Comment: @David Also, that should be `struct _BLOCK *nextBlock;` since the compiler reads from top to bottom and when it sees `Block *nextBlock;`, it will be like 'Hey, what's `Block`? I haven't seen it being defined anywhere' and will throw an error.

Comment: @CoolGuy yeah your right, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

The missing semicolon doesn't help, but you have a bigger issue.

The typedef name `Block` isn't introduced until *after* the struct definition is complete, so you can't use it in the declaration for `nextBlock`.  You have two choices at this point:

1. Use `struct _BLOCK` for the declaration:

   ```
   struct _BLOCK *nextBlock;
   ```

   Forward declare the struct and typedef name:

   ```
   struct _BLOCK;
   typdef struct _BLOCK Block;
   struct _BLOCK {
     ...
     Block *nextBlock;
     ...
   };
   ```

Nits:

Do not use leading underscores for your variable or type names; such names are reserved for the implementation.  IOW, the compiler may define a symbol `_BLOCK` for its own purposes, and your use of `_BLOCK` may lead to a namespace collision.  Use `struct BLOCK` or `struct Block` or something like that instead.

Also, be judicious in your use of typedefs.  If anyone using `Block` has to be aware that it's a `struct` type, then you're better off just using `struct Block`.  Look at the `FILE` type as an example; you are not meant to manipulate the contents of a `FILE` object directly, you just pass a pointer to it to the various `stdio` routines.  You, as the programmer, don't need to know what a `FILE` object looks like on the inside, so in that case it's appropriate to hide it behind a typedef.

If anyone using your `Block` type has to access the `size`, `offset`, or `nextBlock` members *directly*, then it's better make its `struct`-ness explicit.  OTOH, if you're providing an API to manipulate or access block members (similar to the `FILE` type and `stdio` routines), then the typedef is okay.

*Never* hide pointers behind typedefs.